# Converting bytearray containing NUL to string

Tags: java, string, arrays

To the background: I get a String of byte[] from a MYSQL database which looks as follows:

```
s:12:"NUL*NUL_messages";
```

This I want to convert in Java to a string:

```
String str = new String(sd);
```

But now the string contains only 10 characters:

```
s:12:"*_messages";
```

But it needs to have 12 characters so that the following parsing works. Can someone help me what to do so that the "NUL" bytes are not deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` inside the string output stands for the character with the code point of zero. Your string is equivalent to this:

```
String s = "\0*\0_messages";
```

In Java `\0` is non-printable. However, the string preserves it - if you check the length of the string, it's 12, not 10, although only ten characters are printed when you output the string to a console:

```
System.err.println(s.length());
System.err.println(s);
```

prints ([demo](http://ideone.com/l73Lto))

```
12
*_messages
```

> *comment:* This does not work with the [`serialized-php-parser`](https://code.google.com/p/serialized-php-parser/source/browse/src/main/java/org/lorecraft/phparser/SerializedPhpParser.java)

The problem with that parser is that its `parseString` method, line 156, expects the length of the printed string to match the number of characters in the `s:<length>:` construct. Since the declared `<length>` is 12 but the actual length is only 10, `parseString` consumes two extra characters from the stream on lines 175..176, breaking everything else.

If you would like to stay with that parser, consider replacing `'\0'` characters with some other printable character that you do not use, say, an underscore, before encoding the string, and then placing `'\0'` back on the other side of the parse.

Comment: I understand. Thank you. But my problem is that the following parsing with "serialized-php-parser" http://goo.gl/jBqm8E don't works if this NUL values are in the string. Is it possible that `int delimiter = input.indexOf(':', index);` fails in `private int readLength()`?

Comment: Actually, `System.out.println("\0*\0_messages");` doesn't print anything and `System.out.println("sta\0*\0_messages");` only prints `sta`. I am running 1.6 openjdk.

Comment: @rocketboy This must be a problem with the open JDK then. Please follow the `demo` link above to see how this works with Java 7 JDK.

Comment: @rocketboy, no readLength() can not be the problem as it only reads out the 12 as length. The problem must be in parseString()

Comment: If I change `if ((ch >= 0x0001) && (ch <= 0x007F))` to `if ((ch >= 0x0000) && (ch <= 0x007F))` it works. But is it ok to do so?

Comment: @Wotim It looks like the parser is trying to prevent you from embedding zeros in the body of the string. I am not familiar with the internals of PHP, but good chances are that it uses C strings, thus prohibiting embedded NULLs (C uses NULL character for string termination). If interoperability with PHP is the goal, then replacing 0x0001 with 0x0000 is likely to be a breaking change. On the other hand, if it's Java-to-Java, there may be no issues with this change.

Comment: It looks broken as-is. It appears to be reading the null, but not counting it so additional characters are consumed. The change @timmornYE should be made.